# Automatic script conversion js to jsx in react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs

I'm new to REACT so be patient if I confuse terms.

The following html document starts an react app:

**index.html**

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="react@*" data-semver="15.5.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.0/react.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="react@*" data-semver="15.5.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="redux@*" data-semver="3.2.1" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.2.1/redux.js"></script>
    <script data-require="react-redux@*" data-semver="4.4.5" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/4.4.5/react-redux.js"></script>
    <title>Hello world</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Share a sport activity</h1>
    <div id="appMount"></div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

In the same folder as this index.html on the server there is an `app.jsx` file but no `app.js` file (see the src attribute of the script tag).

**app.jsx**

```
class Communicator extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {message: this.props.message};
  }

  resetComm() {
    this.setState({message: ''});
  }
(...)
```

Magically, the index.html document sources the app.jsx file anyway. If I look at dev tools what has been delivered for the `app.js` file the ouput starts with

```
'use strict';

var _createClass = function () { function definePr...
```

which is not the content of the actual app.jsx. So, there is some server-side compiling involved.

So, I understand that the app.jsx file needs pre-compiling to js. I think (after some investigation) this server-side tranlation is done by babeljs and done on-the-fly.

## The problem

If I run the index.html locally it gives me errors in the console that (of course) app.js is not found.

## Question

How can I make my localhost environment (WAMP) behave like the server (it is the online editor platform plunkr.co). I have npm installed. I want it on-the-fly, even if that's slow and not recommended for production.

Everything that I find involves at least the setting of a proper script type

```
<script type="text/babel" src="app.js"></script>
```

but I would like to reproduce the exact same behavior of the server. Basically, I want the index.html (which seems to me a proper standalone app as it works on the server) to run on my local server. I think there is some babeljs setup required which I don't seem to understand.

## Edit

By the way. The example was in a plunker at http://plnkr.co/

## Edit 2

If I add babel.min.js to the header and add a .babelrc as suggested by @Eric it doesn't find the app.js still. If I source app.jsx it finds it but sources it as is. Also, the react app doesn't start.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you're asking. Can you more clearly state what your desired outcome is?

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me. I updated the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the rest of your project setup, I can't tell how the current **app.js** file is getting created, but you're right: what you need is to transpile the code via Babel. This can be done two ways in development: on the dev server (recommended), or in the dev browser using standalone Babel.

#### On the Dev Server (Recommended)

React's recommended way to start with React is using a tool called [Create React App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). Since you said you're new to React, this will take care of Babel behind the scenes and give you a development server (so you don't need WAMP, only Node and NPM), and a build process to create the assets like **app.js** to deliver to the production server.

If you don't have time to immediately learn Babel and Webpack, I'd recommend using Create React App first.

#### In the Dev Browser

If you don't want to introduce a new tool, and you just want to transpile JSX with minimal configuration, you can do this in the browser via [the instructions](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation). This used to be demonstrated in the React.js tutorials until they switched to recommending Create React App. The instructions for installing "in the browser" require two things: adding babel.min.js to your `<head>`, and adding the `type="text/babel"` attribute to your .jsx file (working code example below). However, the documentation gives this advice:

> Compiling in the browser has a fairly limited use case, so if you are 
>   working on a production site you should be precompiling your scripts 
>   server-side. See setup build systems for more information.

Your HTML and JavaScript should look as follows (I've omitted a lot of your code for brevity):

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <script src=src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.0/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.0/react-dom.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Browser in JSX Demo</h1>
  <div id="appRoot">If you're seeing this, it's not working.</div>
  <script type="text/babel" src="app.jsx"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.jsx**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>It works!</div>;
  }
}

const el = document.getElementById('appRoot');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, el);
```

Please note that the extensions used in the script `src` attribute and the JavaScript file must match. You can use `.jsx` or `.js`, but they must match. I don't know how your server is working its magic, but that's beyond the scope of the question, and is not expected behavior by default.

Comment: This "works" in the way that I get an 177 mb demo app running on localhost:3000. However, running my index.html + app.js in combination requires a different file structure. I appreciate the suggestion but right now I am looking for a simple solution to mirror the given setup.

Comment: I've added the instructions from my other answer, now deleted, on how to achieve this in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack) to achieve what you want.

You can download every dependencies like this (if you have npm installed):
`npm install --save-dev webpack`
`npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server`
`npm install --save-dev loader-utils html-webpack-plugin extract-text-webpack-plugin`
`npm install --save-dev babel-core babel-loader babel-register`
`npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react`

Then you can create the file `webpack.config.js` at the root of your folder with this code inside:

```
import path from 'path';  
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';

export default () => ({  
  entry: [
    path.join(__dirname, 'src/index.jsx'),
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: './src/index.html'
    }),
  ]
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel',
            options: {
              babelrc: false,
              presets: [
                ['es2015', { modules: false }],
                'react',
              ],
            }
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
});
```

And in your `package.json`, add those lines:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack"
  }
  ...
}
```

You will now be able to run `npm run dev` for development and `npm run build` to compile the code ready for a production server.

You can init npm in your project if it's not already done like this `npm init`

You can also follow this guide: [Setting Up A React Workflow with Babel and Webpack 2](http://kloc.io/setting-up-react-workflow-babel-webpack/)

Webpack is basically a tool that takes every .jsx file and convert it to a .js file. In the code above, I use index.jsx as the main file. Every react component that will be imported in this file will be automatically computed.